# Problem fitting quadratic model in 'dosresmeta' package due to error regarding "leading minor"

Tags: meta-analysis, error-message, dose-response

I am trying to use the `doresmeta`  package in R to evaluate the dose-response relationship between supplemental intake of a micronutrient and risk of a disease.

When I try to fit a quadratic model for the association between supplemental intake and disease risk using a dataset (9 studies and 26 exposure values), I run into an error saying:

```r
Error in chol.default(X[[i]], ...):  the leading minor of order 15 is 
    not positive definite
```

When I remove row 15 of the dataset, a similar error appears still:

```r
Error in chol.default(X[[i]], ...):  the leading minor of order 18 is 
    not positive definite
```

This error no longer occurs when I remove both rows and 15 and 18 of the dataset, both of which belongs to one particular study with 5 exposure categories.

I am not sure what the meaning of this error could be. Does anyone have an idea of what minor means in such an instance, and why should it be positive definite?  Interestingly enough, I am able to fit a quadratic model when I use only data from that study. The error also doesn’t occur when I try to fit a restricted cubic spline model instead.

I have tried to look for people who ran into similar problems, one of them reported overfitting and resolved the issue by dropping predictor variables (not sure in this case as I only have two predictor variable – dose and dose^sq ) or not having a symmetrical log RRs (I don’t think it’s applicable int his case as there was no error when I tried to fit a quadratic model in just the study with problematic points).

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error 
messages, code or packages, etc.) are generally off topic 
here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.